# Problema con IIS y PDO oci

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, iis

Estoy subiendo una aplicación web, que tiene código php, y en concreto, código PDO para conectar a una base de datos oracle con oci.

El problema es que el php que está instalado en la IIS, muestra varios PDO menos el que necesito, y en php.ini, sí que está.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo necesito para que mi código funcione:

```
function connection(){
    try{
        $tns = '
            (DESCRIPTION =
                (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
                (CONNECT_DATA =
                    (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
                )
            )
        ';
        $pdo_string = 'oci:dbname='.$tns;
        $userBBDD = 'siade';
        $passBBDD = 'siade';
        $conn  = new PDO($pdo_string, $userBBDD, $passBBDD);
        return $conn;
    }catch(Exception $e){

        die('Error: ' . $e->GetMessage());

    }
}
```